# docker-compose wait-for.sh fails for waiting mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a docker network with simple nodejs and mongodb services by following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/containerizing-a-node-js-application-for-development-with-docker-compose), however, when building nodejs it fails because it can't connect to `mongodb`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  nodejs:
    container_name: nodejs # How the container will appear when listing containers from the CLI
    image: node:10 # The <container-name>:<tag-version> of the container, in this case the tag version aligns with the version of node
    user: node # The user to run as in the container
    working_dir: "/app" # Where to container will assume it should run commands and where you will start out if you go inside the container
    networks:
      - app # Networking can get complex, but for all intents and purposes just know that containers on the same network can speak to each other
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # <host-port>:<container-port> to listen to, so anything running on port 3000 of the container will map to port 3000 on our localhost
    volumes:
      - ./:/app # <host-directory>:<container-directory> this says map the current directory from your system to the /app directory in the docker container
    command: # The command docker will execute when starting the container, this command is not allowed to exit, if it does your container will stop
      - ./wait-for.sh
      - --timeout=15
      - mongodb:27017
      - --
      - bash
      - -c
      - npm install && npm start
    env_file: ".env"
    environment: 
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=mongodb
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.1.8-xenial
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    volumes:  
      - dbdata:/data/db 
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
   driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
var server = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// getting-started.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://simpleUser:123456@mongodb:27017/simpleDb', {useNewUrlParser: true});

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000');
});
```

Here is the common `wait-for.sh` script that I was using. https://github.com/eficode/wait-for/blob/master/wait-for

`docker logs -f nodejs` gives;

```
Operation timed out
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: nodejs driver does wait for mongodb by its own. The default connectTimeoutMS is 30 sec - twice as much as you set in the wait-for parameters. The problem is elsewhere. Check mongo logs, try to login manually from nodejs container, etc

Comment: Yes you were right @AlexBlex. The problem was because of the image I was using doesn't have `nc` command installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I believe the issue is that you are using the wait-for.sh script which makes use of `netcat` command (see https://github.com/eficode/wait-for/blob/master/wait-for#L24), but the node:10 image does not have netcat installed...

I would suggest either creating a custom image based on the node:10 image and adding netcat or use a different approach (preferably a nodejs based solution) for checking if the mongodb is accessible

A sample Dockerfile for creating your own custom image would look something like this

```
FROM node:10

RUN apt update && apt install -y netcat
```

Then you can build this image by replacing `image: node:10` with

```
build: 
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  context: .
```

and you should be fine

Comment: You are right Karlis. I switched to another image `node:10-alpine`. Don't know if there is much difference between node:10 and the alpine version.

Comment: Alpine is a very stripped down linux version. It's very lightweight and I use it myself if there is no specific reason not to. One thing to note though is that alpine uses musl instead of glibc (which is used by a lot of other linux based OS's) so there can be small differences in some core functionality (like date formatting etc)
https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html
Other than that - Alpine is a good option for creating a lightweight image for your application

Comment: ah I see. makes sense. Thanks again Karlis!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem which was because of the image `node:10` doesn't have `nc` command installed so it was failing. I switched to image `node:10-alpine` and it worked.