# ERROR: Connection refused while running the Docker-compose up

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I used SpringBoot rest api and MongoDB. I have three different DataBases such as player-db, game-db and score-db. for each services I have DockerFiles.
when I run docker-compose up I've Getting an Error:
The error in docker-shell:

```
 game-docker_1    | 2020-06-12 09:12:03.795  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mon
godb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting
 to server localhost:27017
game-docker_1    |
game-docker_1    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socke
t
game-docker_1    |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:70) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
game-docker_1    |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnect
ion.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

game-docker_1    |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$
ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.1
1.2.jar!/:na]
game-docker_1    |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
game-docker_1    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Con
nection refused)
game-docker_1    |      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 ~[na:1.8.0_252]
game-docker_1    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPl
ainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
game-docker_1    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Abs
tractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
game-docker_1    |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlai
nSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
game-docker_1    |      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java
:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
game-docker_1    |      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_2
52]
game-docker_1    |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.in
itialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
game-docker_1    |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initiali
zeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
game-docker_1    |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
game-docker_1    |      ... 3 common frames omitted
game-docker_1    |
player-docker_1  | 2020-06-12 09:12:03.810  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mon
godb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting
 to server localhost:27017
player-docker_1  |
player-docker_1  | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socke
t
player-docker_1  |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:70) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
player-docker_1  |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnect
ion.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

player-docker_1  |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$
ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.1
1.2.jar!/:na]
player-docker_1  |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
player-docker_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Con
nection refused)
player-docker_1  |      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 ~[na:1.8.0_252]
player-docker_1  |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPl
ainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
player-docker_1  |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Abs
tractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
player-docker_1  |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlai
nSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
player-docker_1  |      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java
:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
player-docker_1  |      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_2
52]
player-docker_1  |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.in
itialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
player-docker_1  |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initiali
zeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
player-docker_1  |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
player-docker_1  |      ... 3 common frames omitted
player-docker_1  |
score-docker_1   | 2020-06-12 09:12:03.893  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mon
godb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting
 to server localhost:27017
score-docker_1   |
score-docker_1   | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socke
t
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:70) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnect
ion.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]

score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$
ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.1
1.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Con
nection refused)
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPl
ainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Abs
tractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlai
nSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java
:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
score-docker_1   |      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_2
52]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.in
itialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initiali
zeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(Soc
ketStream.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
score-docker_1   |      ... 3 common frames omitted
score-docker_1   |
game-docker_1    | 2020-06-12 09:12:06.823  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c
oncurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTas
kExecutor'
player-docker_1  | 2020-06-12 09:12:06.895  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.c
oncurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTas
kExecutor'
```

The docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    player-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/player/DockerFile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db
    game-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/game/DockerFile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8080
        depends_on:
            - db1
    score-docker:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./src/main/java/spring/multiple/mongo/project/score/Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8082:8080
        depends_on:
            - db2 
    db:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: player-db
    db1:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db1
        ports:
            - 27018:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: game-db
    db2:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db2
        ports:
            - 27019:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: score-db
volumes:
    mongodata:
```

I do not know how to solve this problem.
I am beginner in Docker.

Comment: Mongo db starts asynchronously. It reports the container is up (resolves depends_on directives) as soon as the server starts. It takes some time to load data and start listening on the port. There are number of commonly used scripts to solve the problem on different languages e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579542/docker-compose-wait-for-sh-fails-for-waiting-mongodb/56581129

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the network. Kindly understand that each container is a kind of a separate VM. Here, You are trying to connect to localhost. This will not work as each of the containers will resolve to it's own Loop back.

You can solve this in multiple ways:

1. Since all the containers are connected to the same docker network you can use container names to resolve respective ones. So here you can use `db:27017` to connect to MongoDB.**(Recommended)**
2. Since you have port bonded all the containers you can use  of the host machine instead of localhost. So if your host machine's private IP is `10.0.0.1` then use `10.0.0.1:27017` to connect to MongoDB.
3. Use host network, in this case, port binding instruction will be useless as it will be ignored and every service gets bonded automatically to their own port and you can use localhost to connect each of them **(Not recommended)**

References:

1. [Networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/)
2. [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)
3. [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: thank you. In fact I used db:27017 and container_name: ..... but nothing changed and the error is same as before. In addition, this error is in docker-shell and in the Postman I tried both, with localhost and with mashine IP. but because of these errors for all services, the Postman does not work

Comment: did you try using private ip for connecting to db? Also make sure you specify container_name: db in db service. If container_name is not specified in docker-compose file docker creates container with custom name which might sometimes create confusion.

Comment: No, I do not have any information about that. Other thing, I think these Errors are for the part of SpringBoot App. , but I am not sure

Comment: I defined like this:  db:
        image: mongo
        container_name: player-db-container
        volumes:
            - mongodata:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_DATABASE: player-db  @Mani

Comment: since you have specified container_name. It should be used for resolving the ip as it overrides service name in docker. Hence you need to use `player-db-container:27017` in spring boot instead of db:27017` . This is the reason `db:27017` is not working.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested me, but when I used docker-compose up, it wentrs to the loop, shows for example player-db-container exited with code 14 and again start working and again shows that one. @Mani

Comment: my DockerFile is: FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar player.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://player-db-container:27017/","-jar","-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1", "player.jar"], @Mani

Comment: now you have a problem with mysql container. u need to fix it. check why it is not running. There is no problem with JAR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215814/discussion-between-mani-and-user8903246).